# Placing Delete icon on the corner of the image using jquery php css

Tags: php, jquery, css

Here am throwing the images from database to a div in php while, here I want to delete the image by clicking on the delete icon which has to be in the top right corner of the every image pulled from db. How could I get a delete icon in the top right corner of the images?   This is how I am displaying the images in a dialog box.

```
<?php        
$query = "SELECT * FROM files_images";    
$res = mysql_query($query);     
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<div id='popimages'>";
    echo "<img title='$row[img]' id='$row[id]' style='width:100px;float:left; height:100px;margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;border:2px solid #b06c1c;border-radius:10px;' src='http://localhost/PhpProject2/user_data/" . $row['filename'] . "'/>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: any fiddle link or any images.

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: What you want to do then is have the delete image icon in a div along with the image, then position the delete icon to where is needed.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, try outputting something like this :

HTML

```
  <div id='popimages'>
      <div class="image">
          <img class="btn-delete" onclick="alert('Do something!');" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/101.png"/>
          <img title='$row[img]' id='$row[id]' style='width:100px;float:left; height:100px;margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;border:2px solid #b06c1c;border-radius:10px;' src='http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2011/03/16/Chrome-logo-2011-03-16.jpg'/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
}
.btn-delete {
   position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer;
   right: 2px;
   top: 2px;

   /* This was edited out because it was stupid. See fernholz's answer.
   left: 100%; 
   margin-left: -10px;
   margin-top: 2px; */
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TK7zB/

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your image with a `<div>` and place your image and delete link inside that `<div>`.
I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbhPa/) for you, that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Drewman is technically correct, I would change .btn-delete's style to be

```
.btn-delete {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   right: 2px;
   top: 2px;
}
```

The top and right can be changed to whatever distance in from the corner you want the delete icon.

Adrenaxus, was pretty close, but needed a height and width on the image div and position relative, not absolute on it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="img-pos">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-pos{
    position: relative;
}
.img-pos.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: consider explaining your answer. code-only answers are discouraged.